# How to optimize Oracle create table function for a table having over 30 million rows and 250 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, parallel-processing, database-partitioning

I need to create a table which has over 30 million rows and about 250 columns from another table which has same row number and about 230 columns. It is like ETL process. I use SPSS Modeler to run a stream which has  algorithms of the process. I need to make faster the this process.

In IBM Netezza, this process took about 20-25 mins with in-database caching in SPSS Modeler and `DISTRIBUTE ON HASH` function for both input and output tables.

In Oracle, same process took about 1.5-2 hours. I cannot optimize the code. I have tried so many ways, creating both input and output table with PARALLEL function, tried to indexing input table, tried to partitioning and etc.

At last, I have used the syntax in the below for  input and output tables, however I cannot make any progress.

```sql
COLUMN STORE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH NO ROW LEVEL LOCKING  NOLOGGING 
PARTITION BY HASH ("COLUMN 1") PARALLEL 16
```

Comment: My input table has the following properties. Sorry, I cannot give you the actual names of columns
`COLUMN STORE COMPRESS FOR QUERY HIGH NO ROW LEVEL LOCKING  NOLOGGING 
    PARTITION BY HASH ("MUSTERI_NO") 
  PARALLEL 16 
`

Comment: What part of it is taking the time?

Comment: So this is just a copy from one table to another on the same database?  Normally all you need is `create table table1 nologging parallel 16 as select * from table2;`, possibly followed by `alter table table1 logging noparallel;`.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to create the new table using hash partitioning and parallel processing. This here [centroid article](https://centroid.com/parallel-execution-and-partitioning/) seems to be a good discussion to get you started on how to implement it.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think that I have already implemented this method. My input table has hash partitioning and parallel degree 16. I also create my output table same way.